# Javascript Input and output on HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm from the world of Java and I tried to rewrite my Java code that I created in Eclipse. I want to integrate it to an html webpage. Based on a users answer I rewrote the Code to javascript, but it still doesn't work.
The scripts purpose is to process 3 variables provided by user and output 5 calculated results. Basically I'm not sure if the connection between html and javascript is correct. The logic itself should work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>


   Teilnehmer Deutschland: <input type= "text" id= "TNDV">

   Teilnehmer Partner: <input type= "text" id= "TNPV">

   Anzahl Nächte: <input type= "text" id= "NV">

   <button onclick = "berechnung()">test </button>

   <p id="TNBI"></p>
   <p id="TNBE"></p>
   <p id="TNBA"></p>
   <p id="TNBG"></p>
   <p id="FP"></p>


 </body> 

  <script>
  var berechnung = (function () {
   function berechnung() {
   }
   berechnung.main = function (args) {
   var TND = document.getElementById("TNDV").value;
   var TNP = document.getElementById("TNPV").value;
   var N = document.getElementById("NV").value;
    var TNBI;
    var TNBE;
    var TNBA;
    var TNBG;
    var FP;
    if (N >= 4) {
        TNBE = (10 * N);
        TNBI = (8 * N);
        TNBA = (4 * N);
    }
    else {
        TNBE = (10 * N);
        TNBI = (4 * N);
        TNBA = (0);
    }
    if (TNP + TND >= 16) {
        TNBG = (TNBI * (TND - 2) * 1 / 3 + TNBE * (TND - 2) * 2 / 3 +   TNBA * (TNP - 2));
    }
    else if (TNP + TND >= 10) {
        TNBG = (TNBI * (TND - 1) * 1 / 3 + TNBE * (TND - 1) * 2 / 3 + TNBA * (TNP - 1));
    }
    else {
        TNBG = (TNBI * (TND - 1) * 1 / 3 + TNBE * (TND - 1) * 2 / 3 + TNBA * TNP);
    }
    if (TND + TNP >= 16) {
        FP = 4;
    }
    else if (TND + TNP >= 10) {
        FP = 2;
    }
    else {
        FP = 1;
    }
     document.getElementById("TNBI").innerText = `Intern: ${TND}`;
     document.getElementById("TNBE").innerText = `Extern: ${TNP}`;  
     document.getElementById("TNBA").innerText = `Partner: ${N}`;
     document.getElementById("TNBA").innerText = `Freie Plätze: ${FP}`;
     document.getElementById("TNBA").innerText = `Gesamt: ${TNBG}`;

  };
  return berechnung;
  }());
  berechnung["__class"] = "berechnung";
  berechnung.main(null);

   </script>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, JavaScript is a misnomer, it has absolutely no relation to Java. If you're trying to rewrite your Java code in JavaScript, that is a possibility; however, JavaScript isn't a typed language, so things like "String" mean nothing, and there is no Double in JavaScript.

Here's my best guess at what you're trying to accomplish.

#### Solution

```js
function berechnung() {
    var TND = parseInt(document.getElementById("TNDV").value);
    var TNP = parseInt(document.getElementById("TNPV").value);
    var N = parseInt(document.getElementById("NV").value);
    var TNBI, TNBE, TNBA, TNBG, FP;
    if (N >= 4) {
        TNBE = (10 * N);
        TNBI = (8 * N);
        TNBA = (4 * N);
    }
    else {
        TNBE = (10 * N);
        TNBI = (4 * N);
        TNBA = (0);
    }
    if (TNP + TND >= 16) {
        TNBG = (TNBI * (TND - 2) * 1 / 3 + TNBE * (TND - 2) * 2 / 3 + TNBA * (TNP - 2));
    }
    else if (TNP + TND >= 10) {
        TNBG = (TNBI * (TND - 1) * 1 / 3 + TNBE * (TND - 1) * 2 / 3 + TNBA * (TNP - 1));
    }
    else {
        TNBG = (TNBI * (TND - 1) * 1 / 3 + TNBE * (TND - 1) * 2 / 3 + TNBA * TNP);
    }
    if (TND + TNP >= 16) {
        FP = 4;
    }
    else if (TND + TNP >= 10) {
        FP = 2;
    }
    else {
        FP = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("TNBI").innerText = `Intern: ${TND}`;
    document.getElementById("TNBE").innerText = `Extern: ${TNP}`;
    document.getElementById("TNBA").innerText = `Partner: ${N}`;
    document.getElementById("TNBA").innerText = `Freie Plätze: ${FP}`;
    document.getElementById("TNBA").innerText = `Gesamt: ${TNBG}`;

};
```

```html
Teilnehmer Deutschland: <input type= "text" id= "TNDV"><br>
Teilnehmer Partner: <input type= "text" id= "TNPV"><br>
Anzahl Nächte: <input type= "text" id= "NV"><br>
<button onclick="berechnung()">results</button>

<p id="TNBI"></p>
<p id="TNBE"></p>
<p id="TNBA"></p>
<p id="TNBG"></p>
<p id="FP"></p>
```